# Add & Stop while running the project in XCode4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, build-process, compilation

When we hit run button in XCode4 & if project is already running,
it prompts as follows.

[image]

My question is

what does it will do if I tap on Add button ?
Does it means, add local changes quickly to build/running application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it will run the program without stopping the old one

Answer (score 1):

It will start the new compiled app without stopping the old build so your app runs two times now. This is useful if you have a workspace with two different apps that should both run simultaneously but more or less useless if you work on a single app.